# How to get around the 1023GB disk limit for Azure Recovery Vault?

Tags: backup, azure, windows-server-2016

I have several VM's in Azure that use 2 or 4TB disks or use striped disks (4x4TB), Azure Backup doesn't let me backup VM's that have disks attached that are greater than 1023GB, is there a way around this?

Is using the Azure backup agent an option that is normally used for non-azure servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for larger disks is coming, but there's no ETA yet. It's currently in Private Preview. For now, there's no workaround besides waiting for the feature to be released. Using Azure Backup Agent is an option if all you need to backup are files and folders.